# how can i display data frames in spyder?

Tags: python, spyder

I want to see the head of a data frame on spyder. in the variable explorer it only shows me the entire data frame.

when i use `print(data_frame.head())` , i see on the console only the first and last columns, and its also not very pleasant to see data frames on the console in spyder. on the contrary in jupyter it looks very good an convinient.

below you can see how i see data frames on spyder's console, how can i see all the columns like in jupyter?
and also on spyder i must use `print()` to display the output, unless i run a single line.

```
   order_id  ...  item_price
0         1  ...      $2.39 
1         1  ...      $3.39 
2         1  ...      $3.39 
3         1  ...      $2.39 
4         2  ...     $16.98 
5         3  ...     $10.98 
6         3  ...      $1.69 
7         4  ...     $11.75 
8         4  ...      $9.25 
9         5  ...      $9.25
```

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You said

> how can i see all the columns like in jupyter?

That's not possible at the moment, sorry.

Instead, you need to use our Variable Explorer to view dataframes. There we display all variables that you've created in the console. After double-clicking on your dataframe, Spyder will show its contents in a separate window, like this

[image: Dataframe in Spyder]

Comment: my pandas dataframe is not listed in the variable explorer list